# Invoke-RestMethod and foreach loop

Tags: rest, powershell

Via PowerShell I'm trying to get the last ticker data from all currency pairs via the public API of a cryptocurrency exchange.
For this I first get all markets and then I want to loop through these, but for some reason only the first currency pair is being returned.

Anyone knows what I'm missing?

```
$bt_baseapi_url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/"
$getmarkets = $bt_baseapi_url + "public/getmarkets"
$getticker = $bt_baseapi_url + "public/getticker"

$markets = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getmarkets
$marketnames = $markets.result

foreach ($marketname in $marketnames.marketname) {
    $tickerurl = $getticker + "?market=" + $marketname
    $ticker = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tickerurl
    return $ticker.result.last
}
```

Comment: Don't `return` if you don't want to return in the first place.

Comment: ah, Powershell newbie here. 

I added the return for testing purposes to see the output not realizing that that would exit the loop.

I now removed it and loop is working now. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ansgar Wiechers suggests in a comment on the question, **do not use `return` inside a `foreach` *statement*'s body** in an attempt to return (output) a value while continuing the loop; `return` would return from any enclosing *function* or *script*.

Instead, **rely on PowerShell's implicit output behavior**, as demonstrated in this simple example:

```
> foreach ($el in 1, 2, 3) { $el }
1
2
3
```

Simply referencing `$el` without assigning to a variable or piping / redirecting it elsewhere cause its value to be *output*.

If needed at all, **use `continue` to prevent execution of subsequent statements in the loop body** while continuing the loop overall; use `break` to *exit* the loop.

---

By contrast - and that may be the source of the confusion - **inside the body of a `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* call** - as part of a *pipeline* - rather than the `foreach` *statement*, the rules change, and **`return` indeed would only exit the iteration at hand** and proceed with the next input object:

```
> 1, 2, 3 | ForEach-Object { return $_ }
1
2
3
```

- Note that even in this case `return $_` is just syntactic sugar for `$_; return` - i.e., an output generating statement followed by a control-flow statement, and simply using `$_` may be enough.
- **Do NOT use `break` / `continue` with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet**, as these statements would look for an *enclosing* loop *statement* (such as `foreach`, `do`, while`) and - in the absence of one - exit the entire *script*.

  - Unfortunately, there is no direct way to *exit* a pipeline prematurely, - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821; make your voice heard there if you think this should change.